# How to convert string column to time column type?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a column in this format

[image: Original format]

when I ingest the data, it is in a string format.
When I tried to convert it to timespan, the values disappear
[image: After converting to timespan data type]

How can I convert string column to timespan?

Answer (score 3):

You could try using `parse` and then `make_timespan()`, or timespan arithmetics:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-timespanfunction
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator

For example:

```
T
| parse event_time with minutes:int ":" seconds:int "." ms:int
| project result = minutes * 1m + seconds * 1s + ms * 100 * 1ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [format_timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-timespanfunction) Kusto function with `fffffff` formatter.

**Example**

```
format_timespan(time(29.09:00:05.12345), 'ddd.h:mm:ss [fffffff]')
```

Result: 029.9:00:05 [1234500]