# How to convert todatetime to seconds in azure kusto query

Tags: azure, unix-timestamp, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

For example, I have a query,

```
workspace("someanalytics").somecheck
| where someProperties_s contains "something"
| project someProperties_s , TimeGenerated
| extend somethingAB = parse_json(someProperties_s)
| extend somethingabc= somethingAB.something
| project TimeGenerated, tostring(somethingabc)
| order by TimeGenerated, somethingabc desc
| extend somethingabcchart = somethingabc
| parse somethingabcchart with minutes:int ":" seconds:int "." ms:int
```

oldresults before parse

TimeGenerated [UTC]   :       somethingabc  : somethingabcchart

9/8/2021, 9:37:01.532 AM    :   00:27.49     :   00:27.49
9/8/2021, 9:38:22.112 AM     :  00:25.67    :   00:25.67
9/8/2021, 9:39:51.473 AM    :   00:30.50     :   00:30.50
9/8/2021, 9:41:31.722 AM    :   00:33.89    :    00:33.89
9/8/2021, 9:43:01.623 AM    :   00:28.10    :    00:28.10
9/8/2021, 9:44:31.567 AM    :   00:27.18    :    00:27.18

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h6L6.jpg)

The image shows the current result after checking this link [How to convert string column to time column type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072531/how-to-convert-string-column-to-time-column-type)
Here I would like to get the timestamp date to be converted to just seconds, as you can see in the image it should give 95 seconds under "somethingabcchart" column

00:27.49  gives just 27 seconds
if its is
01.01.00 then just 61 seconds as results under somethingabc column or in somethingabcchart column, as it is in timestampdate it is not possible to create a chart on azure query, so need a way to convert into seconds.I am trying to convert it to string because it thought later part of the code it can be converted back to timedate then divide by 1 sec to get the seconds but could not get the data, i used this link for guidance. <<
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/timespan

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you can divide a `timespan` value by `1s` to get the total number of seconds.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-timespan-arithmetic

For example:

```
datatable(ts:timespan)[timespan(12:34:56), timespan(1.23:45:23.678)]
| extend total_seconds = ts / 1s // <---
```

| ts | total_seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 12:34:56 | 45296 |
| 1.23:45:23.6780000 | 171923.678 |

or, if the input is a `string` and not a `timespan`:

```
datatable(ts_str:string)["12:34:56", "1.23:45:23.678"]
| extend ts = totimespan(ts_str)
| extend total_seconds = ts / 1s // <---
```

| ts_str | ts | total_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12:34:56 | 12:34:56 | 45296 |
| 1.23:45:23.678 | 1.23:45:23.6780000 | 171923.678 |

Comment: Yes you understand well, as you told I tried the same thing, here in the above example I gave, the value of "somethingabc" is in 00:27.49 , as you can see the column in results, I tried to divide by using  
`extend somethingabcchart = timepsan(somethingabc)/1s` 
it throws error, 
Error as " Query could not be parsed at 'timespan(somethingabc)'

Comment: Please the the updated example. If you still need assistance, I'd recommend that you provide a sample input **using the `datatable` operator**, as done in the examples

Comment: I saw you answered here. the problem is something like this in the attached link as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072531/how-to-convert-string-column-to-time-column-type), as I try to convert it gives empty table and also I would like to get the results only in seconds